# Failed to resolve 'proxy-azure' using Azure openai python package

Tags: azure, langchain, azure-openai

hope you are doing fine!

I am trying to run [this code](https://github.com/pinecone-io/examples/blob/master/learn/generation/langchain/00b-azure-openai-simple.ipynb), but I am facing with an odd error. It started happening today. Before that, I was running a similar chunk of code without any errors. Can you help me with this issue?

```
from langchain.chains            import RetrievalQA
from langchain.chains            import LLMChain
from langchain.chat_models       import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chat_models       import AzureChatOpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.schema import (
    SystemMessage,
    HumanMessage,
    AIMessage
)
import os
import openai
from webapi.config           import Config
from langchain.schema import (
    SystemMessage,
    HumanMessage,
    AIMessage
)


def test_2():

    llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
        openai_api_base    = "https://myopenairesource.openai.azure.com/" + "openai"  , #openai?
        openai_api_key     = "0a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10111251617181920", # whatever key
        openai_api_version = "2023-03-15-preview", # as always
        openai_api_type    = 'azure'             , # as always
        model_name         = "gpt-35-turbo-16k",   # ok, same name model than deployment
    )

    messages = [
        SystemMessage(content="You are ExpertGPT, an AGI system capable of " +
            "anything except answering questions about cheese. " +
            "It turns out that AGI does not fathom cheese as a " +
            "concept, the reason for this is a mystery.")
            ]
    res = llm(messages)
    print(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_2()
```

When executed, the error that pops up is the following:

File "C:\myname.....\env\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 619, in request_raw
raise error.APIConnectionError(
openai.error.APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myresource.openai.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /openai/openai/deployments//chat/completions?api-version=2023-03-15-preview (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001FAD1D25F10>: **Failed to resolve 'proxy-azure'** ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")))

What is going on with this proxy thing? have no idea on why this is happening! any help will be welcome

Comment: Please use `azure_endpoint` instead of `openai_api_base` and set its value to `https://myopenairesource.openai.azure.com/`.